# Sharing Places using Google API/Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am building a collaborative web app to share places and media related to this place .
I am new to Google Maps and still new to Ruby on Rails . I need to have a user to mark a location on a map (using Google Map) then share an event in this map. It's kind of a collaborative tool using a map ?

I can't find an operational code example on Github or blogpost/Tutorial that explain a similar scenario .

Does anyone have one to share? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did this app a while back: http://pinme.herokuapp.com try it out,  if is usefull for you i can share you the source

You can create map pins give them a title and share them with a url,  also they get saved on your pins section

here is the github: https://github.com/kazpsp/pinme

Comment: Great ! You can't save several locations (only one) , but it would be a great start . Can I have a look to the code source (I am the last one who registered) !

Comment: If it helped you,  dont forget to thumbs up and mark as answered